# How to retrieve all headers sent with Http facade in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, curl

Based on this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client you can generate requests via CURL client.
There the option to assert specific is sent with `Http::assertSent` however given a specific request like this

```
Http::withToken('mytoken')->withHeaders([
    'X-First' => 'foo',
])->post('http://test.com/users', [
    'name' => 'Taylor',
    'role' => 'Developer',
]);
```

how to get a raw representation of request headers sent to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for the client outline a way that you can assert a specific header is present, and you can optionally assert the value too; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#inspecting-requests.

Sounds like you want to dump out all the headers though.

If we look in the documentation, when you are asserting a request was sent, you are passed an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Client\Request`.
If we take a look at `Illuminate\Http\Client\Request` there is a public method for getting all the headers:

```
/**
 * Get the request headers.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function headers()
{
    return collect($this->request->getHeaders())->mapWithKeys(function ($values, $header) {
        return [$header => $values];
    })->all();
}
```

So in your test, you could do something like this:

```
Http::fake();

//... your test

Http::assertSent(function ($request) {
    dump($request->headers());

    // replace this with an actual assertion but it’s needed to print the dump out
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Hi, have you tested this? I'm getting *An expected request was not recorded. Failed asserting that false is true.*

Comment: Got it, you have to return *true* to get a result printed, thanks! You may want to update the answer in order to add this.

Comment: I’ve used this method to check stuff before, yes. You’re getting that error because you’re not actually returning true or false from your assertion. I don’t know what you want to assert so I can’t write your assertion for you.